# Optimization in yii2 Grid View loading

Tags: php, optimization, activerecord, gridview, yii2

I am using the yii2 grid view - active record to load data.
I need to join 3 tables in which each table has more than 100k records with search functionality. Combining these table with large data slow downs the loading of Grid.
How to optimize it?

```
$query = ModelName::find();
$query->joinWith(['relationshipTable1', 'relationshipTable2']);
```

Comment: change active record queries to Query builder and select only those columns that you are displaying or filtering

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam, I have tried the same. But the issue is not solved yet.

Comment: i dont know what you have tried until unless you add your code here that you updated, apart from the code it depends on the amount of data you have stored if it is really much you might need to add proper indexes on you table columns too

Answer (score 2):

I think I'm not sure about it

- try to create a new model
- after it fetch you data with join to select the data that you want
- finally try to fetch those data in the new model and it will appear in the grid view
- to optimize the time don't do the join with model there is three way to write query a procedural way where you write your query in the form select ... this manner will give you less time executing cause model using ActiveRecord consumes much time compared to ActiveQuery

Answer (score 0):

Check the table’s structure. Add indexes to the the fields that contains the foreign keys on all tables.